# windows surface onscreen keyboard

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

I was hoping someone could help me with a couple questions I had on the onscreen keyboard on the surface pro 2.

When using the onscreen keyboard in the Facebook app, as well as completing this text box in internet explorer, the keyboard is very efficient.  I am able to type almost as fast as I can on a physical keyboard due to the suggestions and auto corrections provided.

However, this does not actually take place everywhere. When typing s URL there is no auto suggestions, no corrections, nothing.  Working on a text file in notepad on the desktop, same thing.

Is there a way to implement this functionality all of the time, or is this's individual app's responsibility to provide this?

If it required programming, maybe I can also look into this as well, as I am a a.NET programmer.

Comment: @Ramhound Actually the Surface Pro 2 runs on Windows 8.1 Pro, which is a fully functional version of Windows.

Comment: @SamyBencherif - I based my comment based on the title.   You are indeed right about it using Windows 8.1

Comment: @MikeChristiansen You can use other applications that do have the features your looking for. Your knowlege as a .NET programmer won't be helpful in a situation like this.

Comment: So other than hacking/patching existing software, my only recourse is to find a different program? So I need a new browser just to get the autocomplete working in an address bar? Seems like a poor design decision... they should have just made it a function of the keyboard and not the app. Or default to on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your knowledge as a .NET programmer will most definitely be helpful in a situation like this.

Although it may not be worth the effort, an option would be to recreate the applications in question, with added support for text completion.

This shouldn't be very difficult for notepad since there is [a copy](http://dotnetnotepad.codeplex.com/) of its source in .NET.

Also here is a [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1102/Using-the-WebBrowser-control-in-NET) on making a .NET Web Browser.

Finally, this  [Stack Overflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760389/) will be helpful for adding text completion support to the remade applications.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to patch existing software.  Guess it depends on how easy it is to enable this feature.. guess I have some testing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my only recourse is to either find another program, or find some way to change the IsTextPredictionEnabled to true.... which is the default value for WPF apps.  So Microsoft intentionally turned it off, which may be the appropriate action for the address bar....

I might be screwed as far as desktop apps go though....

Thanks for the help!